Self intersection number of diagonal
Suppose I have an elliptic curve $E$. How would I calculate the self intersection in $A_*(E \times E)$ of the diagonal $\Delta$?
It seems the formula I need to use is $\Delta . \Delta = c_1(N_{\Delta/E \times E}). \Delta$ $= c_1(T_E) . \Delta$.
From this we want to calculate $c_1(\mathcal{O}_E).\Delta$ since the tangent bundle of an elliptic curve is trivial. So what would the divisor corresponding to $\mathcal{O}_E$ be? If I pick say $0_E \times E$ then the intersection is $0_E \times 0_E$. Where $0_E$ is the origin. But what if I picked some other divisor it seems like the point I get would be different in Chow.

$c_1$ of the trivial line bundle is $0$, i.e., the $0$-divisor. Note that the answer should be the topological Euler characteristic, which is in fact $0$.

Sorry so is the 0-divisor different than the distinguished point of the elliptic curve?

Yes. Its underlying support is the empty set.

As Ted Shifrin says in the comments, $c_1(0)=0$, so you're done there.
Alternatively, as $\Delta\cong E$, adjunction says $2g_E - 2 = \Delta.(\Delta+K_{E\times E})$. But $g_E=1$, and $K_{E\times E}$ is the sum of $2g_E-2$ horizontal and $2g_E-2$ vertical copies of $E$, so in this case $K_{E\times E}=0$, and we must have $\Delta^2=0$.
This generalizes to show that for any curve $C$ of genus $g$, on the surface $C\times C$ we have $\Delta^2=2-2g$.
